# error in setting a data-attribute in jQuery fn

Tags: jquery

I have a table element in form that posts as a collection in MVC action. When user clicks to add a new row, I clone the first row in jQuery; clear the values and rename the id and name attributes...likewise I update the attributes in case user deletes a row. I had forgotten about changing the element generated by `@Html.ValidationFor()`; which is a span with a `data-valmsg-for` attribute. So, when there was a validation error in a textbox in first row... I was getting the same validation error in the cloned rows. To fix this; I modified the addRow fn to change the `data-valmsg-for` attribute... but its not working so far.

code

```
.... //  code which iterates over input elements in cloned row

  if ($('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').length) {  // getting 1 here

$('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', newName); // not working
}
```

**EDITED** some typos

Comment: Not working not enough to describe the problem .. what is the error you got?? .. for me your code works if you just remove one of `{`  and for sure not use `.attr(` in a new line  `$('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', newName);`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  sorry.. that's a copy paste error. my problem is that the span retains the old 'data-valmsg-for' value

Comment: `.data('valmsg-for', newName)`?

Comment: tried..but same result

Comment: can you create a demo that shows the problem?

Comment: Ok @Shwrk I think you need to work with `<tr>` not with the `<span>` .. you can then use `ClonedRow.find('span')` or you can use `ClonedRow.find('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]')` instead of just using `('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]')` for sure ClonedRow is the variable you saved a cloned row in it .. But your piece of code should work .. if you check the first `<tr>` span it should change its data attribute

Comment: to be clear .. I believe you run this piece of code before append the new row to the table .. so `$('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').length` will return 1 from the previous row not from the clone .. so your code should be something like  `$('tr:first').clone().find('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]')` instead of `('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]')`

Comment: `if ($('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').length) {...` should be compared to some other quantity. `if($('span[data-valmsg-for="' + oldName + '"]').length` **> -1** `) {...`. You should seriously consider using the class attribute for selectors and use `data-*` attributes for trivial data manipulation

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef.. your comments set me on the right track.. the changes I made was not getting binded to the cloneRow object.. I had some success with cloneRow.find().. now finetuning some things.. thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Shwrk glad it helped .. Have a great day :-)